# How to parse json direct from assets folder android without holding it in string

Tags: android, json

I have a very large json file i want to parse it when i try to parse it by simple method it gives me outofmemory exception

```
JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);
```

How it is possible to get specific object from file.

Comment: What is the size of the String? Have you tried requesting a larger heap?

Comment: Do you have other things like big images or something loaded too? Did you check if it crashes when you dont load the json by commenting it?

Comment: No, it is crashed on the line mention in the question.

Comment: you could read the json file with `android.util.JsonReader` for it doesn't load the entire file into memory at once, but if you plan to assemble a json object with all the file content, you will end up running out of memory just the same